# C - Printing out float values

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, precision

I have a C++ program that takes in values and prints out values like this:

```
getline(in,number);
cout << setw(10) << number << endl;
```

I have an equivalent C program that takes in values and prints out like so:

```
fscanf(rhs, "%e", &number);
printf("%lf\n", number);
```

But while the C++ program prints out, `0.30951` the C program prints out `0.309510`. More examples: C++: `0.0956439` C: `0.095644`. It seems to print the same results as long as the value is 7 digits long, but if its shorter the 7 digits, it adds an extra 0 at the end. And if its longer than 7 digits, it rounds down to 6 digits. I would like the C results to match the C++ program. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Note: number is a float and number are read from a file.

Comment: Do you want to change the C results to match the C++ or vice-versa?

Comment: Correct, I want the C result to match the C++.

Answer (score 14):

Take advantage of the length and precision specifiers in C formatted print statements:

```
printf( "%6.4lf", number );
```

Prints four decimal places in a "cell" six characters wide.

You can use a wildcard character for either length or precision to provide that value at runtime:

```
int precision = 4;

printf( "%6.*lf", precision, number );
```

Answer (score 14):

Take advantage of the length and precision specifiers in C++ `iostream`s

```
std::cout.precision(4);
std::cout << std::setw(10) << number << "\n";
```

Comment: You can also set precision directly in that stream: "std::cout << 42.1 << std::setprecision(4) << std::endl;"

Comment: I believe `setw()` requires `#include <iomanip>` otherwise I get the error: "no member named 'setw' in namespace 'std'".

Answer (score 6):

```
printf("%g\n", number);
```

Will solve your problem, %lf is used for double, %f is used for float, and %g is used for float when you want to display all the decimal places and cut off zeros.